# hierarchical image classification in tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification, resnet

I want to do two steps classification. for each input I want to go for classify it to class1, 2, or ... and then based on each class, classify my input to specific class (for example is in first step high score belongs to class2, final label should be class2_1, or ... class2_m).

input image --
              class1
                      class1_1
                      class1_2
              class2
                      class2_1
                         .
                         .
                .
                .
              class n 
                      classn_1
                         .
                         .

I need tensorflow codes sample. Can any one help?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Why do you believe that this is a good network architecture? Why don't you just classify into class1_1 etc. directly?

Comment: You need a multi label classifier

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?